# How to draw shapes only over a specific color in Java?

Tags: java, user-interface, graphics2d

Suppose you have multiple polygons in a 2d graphic and you only want to draw lines, curves, arcs, etc.  where a polygon is, say colored black. How would you go about that?

If you use points that lie on the edge of the polygon to draw shapes, they go over the edges of the polygon.

I know about composing graphics in Java, but if I use that in the situation I described then the strokes are drawn over other polygons as well i.e. they go out of the polygon I choose to draw them in and into other polygons that are besides it since all polygons are part of the same graphic.

Comment: Depends if you want it to be efficient. If I were to do it where efficiency does not matter, I would draw each polygon on different BufferedImage, draw stuff you want over it, and then check each pixel: if it is outside polygon, set it to transparent. After all that stuff is done just draw those BufferedImages in you Graphics2D.

Comment: That is a good work around but I believe it would make handling operations on the final graphic that much more complex especially since the user can interact with the final graphic.

Comment: Are you familiar with clipping?
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/clipping.html